# Type mismatch using range data type

Tags: excel, vba

The code takes two workbooks and copies specific data based off there value into the destination workbook.

It worked previously, but I tweaked it.

```vb
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim StatusCol2 As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range
Dim SCH22 As Workbook
Dim SCH21 As Workbook
Dim BD As Workbook

Set SCH22 = Workbooks.Open("path to first workbook")
Set SCH21 = Workbooks.Open("path to second workbook")
Set BD = Workbooks.Open("path to pasting workbook")

Set StatusCol = SCH22.Sheets("CONTFRM22-23").Range("T2:T5000")
Set StatusCol2 = SCH21.Sheets("CONTFRM20-21").Range("R2:R5000")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2022-23").Range("A2:AC5000").ClearContents
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2020-21").Range("A2:R5000").ClearContents

For Each Status In StatusCol
    If BD.Sheets("2022-23").Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = BD.Sheets("2022-23").Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = BD.Sheets("2022-23").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status.Value > 31 Then Status.Offset(0, -19).Resize(1, 31).Copy PasteCell
    
Next Status

For Each Status In StatusCol2
    If BD.Sheets("2020-21").Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = BD.Sheets("2020-21").Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = BD.Sheets("2020-21").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status.Value > 31 Then Status.Offset(0, -17).Resize(1, 29).Copy PasteCell
    
Next Status

end sub
```

I get a 'Type mismatch' error on the line

```
If Status.Value > 31 Then Status.Offset(0, -17).Resize(1, 29).Copy PasteCell
```

I do not get the error when it runs for the first spreadsheet, only the second spreadsheet.

Comment: Likely `Status` is non-numeric or an error value. What is its value when the error occurs?

Comment: how do i find that out?

Comment: For example, add `Debug.Print Status.Value` before that line, then run and inspect the output in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: will do. Upon inspection of the destination spreadsheet, it does some of it then runs into the error

Comment: The last line of the immediate window says 'Error 2015'

Comment: You should check with `IsError(Status.Value)` or `IsNumeric(Status.Value)` before comparing. And keep in mind you need to do it in if above the one you do the `>13` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The last line of the immediate window says 'Error 2015'

This means that `Status` contains a `#VALUE!` error, which cannot be compared to a number like `31`.

Use [`IsNumeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function) to check before comparing to `31`.

```
If IsNumeric(Status.Value) Then
   If Status.Value > 31 Then 
       Status.Offset(0, -17).Resize(1, 29).Copy PasteCell
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Great, that worked. One question though. I went through the workbook to see where the error values were and there were none in the column it was meant to be looking at. So i am unsure as to why it didnt work without your code?

Comment: You could also `Debug.Print Status.Address` to see which exact cell throws the error.